# How to i change the class name inside <td>

Tags: javascript

```
<table id="results">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>1st</td>
                <td class="horse1"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>1st</td>
                <td class="horse2"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>1st</td>
                <td class="horse3"></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

i used this way it didnt worked .
`document.getElementById("result").className=horseId;`

**horseId**  is an variable and contains value

and there are multiple classes insede so how do i select a specific class to change.

Comment: You forgot quotes for your . classname "horseId"

Comment: you are also selecting `"result"` when it should be `"results"`.

Comment: your caption said you are trying it set it on a td which is several layers down from the object that you have the id on

Comment: The minimum text requirement is designed to get you to **actually state the problem clearly**, and dumping noise in to get past it is extremely disrespectful to this site and the people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**. If you're not willing to follow the site guidelines, you should ask your questions at a different site. *I used this way it didn't work* is not a problem statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed two things; first, you attempted to target by ID `result`, when you need `results`. Second, you need to wrap the desired class names in quotes. You can use a variable for the assignment, assuming the variable maps to a string.

It's also worth mentioning that your existing class `horse1` is several nodes down from your target ID `results`. I **assume** this is the element you're trying to change.

To change the class of the `#results` element, you can use `document.getElementById('results').className = horseId;`.

To change the class of the `.horse1` element, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('horse1').className = horseId;`.

Here's an example of the latter:

```js
var horseId = 'rainbow_dash';
document.getElementsByClassName('horse1').className = horseId;
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('horse1').className);
```

```html
<table id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1st</td>
      <td class="horse1"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -2):

It should be "results"

```
document.getElementById("results").className=horseId;
```